# UnsatisfiedLinkError Can't Load Library

Tags: java, exception, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am working with Proycon for decompiling .class to .java, included jd-core-java-1.0.jar file in my libraries directory, but when I compile the Main class it throw an exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
Can't load library: D:\apps\dvlpr\lib/libjd-intellij.so
```

printed System.getProperty("java.library.path");
it outputed as

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin;
C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;
C:\Windows\system32;
C:\Windows;
C:\Program Files (x86)\PC Connectivity Solution\;
C:\Python33\;
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;
C:\Windows\system32;
C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Toshiba\Bluetooth Toshiba Stack\sys\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Toshiba\Bluetooth Toshiba Stack\sys\x64\;
C:\Program Files\nodejs\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin;
C:\Users\Shajeer\AppData\Roaming\npm;.
```

I have tried many methods like setting class path...,but all are not working.anybody please tell me a good method.

I am using NetBeans 7.4 IDE

Comment: Did you make sure that you have downloaded the Windows version? `libjd-intellij.so` looks like a Unix/Linux shared library, on Windows this should be something like `libjd-intellij.dll`

Comment: @Andreas https://github.com/nviennot/jd-core-java#usage there is only one version is available.

Comment: See your link: `But this wrapper only supports Linux 64-bit`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the link provided in the comments, *JD-Core-java* is a thin-wrapper for the Java Decompiler to support an IntelliJ IDE plugin. The Java Decompiler itself supports:

- Linux 32/64-bit
- Windows 32/64-bit
- Mac OSX 32/64-bit on x86 hardware

**However**, the *JD-Core-java* wrapper currently **only supports Linux 64-bit**.

You have two options:

- Contact the author and ask for a Windows version
- Pull the sources from bitbucket and port the native code to Windows to build a Windows DLL (and send it back to the author to be included in future versions)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to rename `jd-intellij.dll` to `libjd-intellij.dll` in the jd-core-java.jar file. (in META-INF\nativelib\win32\x86_64).